# SOLR how to use "fq" and "bq" together?

Tags: solr, filter

I want the result like it supposed to be from this query:

```
q=how to&fq=book_type:*technical*&bq=author:*Anne*^999

(Select the book records including the Words: "how to", from the Type of: "technical"
and the Author(Anne)'s Books to be putting at the top of the filtered results.)
```

But i can **not** use `fq` and `bq` together.
However the query is working using them separately.

Comment: Is it the fq static too? What about `bq=author:Anne AND book_type:technical^999` ?